# set width and height to a div witour position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to set width and height to my div in css, but it will only work if I have position:absolute and I dont want to have that. Cause when I have position:absolute it wont work out so good on other screens. And I want so it stays that width even if I dont have any text or something! :)

look:

`.menu {
    width:450px;
    height:300px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
}`

but I dont get anything from that...

Thanks! :)

Comment: You should post your HTML as well. Can you make a jsFiddle? Also, what is "now I don't get anything?" That can mean many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare `position:absolute` in order to have `width` and  `height`working. The only restriction is, it has to be a `block-level` element, which `div` is by default. So it should work without problems.

Maybe you have `display:inline` declared on it? If you have so, change it to `display:inline-block;` or omit the display entirely, depending on your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML that you have correctly declared the DIV as a CLASS and you're not using its ID. Sometimes spelling errors can cause the simplest of things to not work.